# Smileys / Emoticons missing in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, emoticons

It seems that certain (not all) emoticons are missing in my Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1 installation. The table of emoticons from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_(Unicode_block)) looks as follows on my system:

[image]

Windows Update [KB2729094](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2729094) which should address this issue is installed.

What can I do to get the missing emoticons? Deciphering them in incoming E-Mails is getting old... :-)

Comment: KB2729094 "An update for the **Segoe UI symbol font**". Not every font can display emojis.

Comment: Well those solutions do not help. I use Gmail in my browser and when I set the font to Segue UI the emojis still don't show correctly.

Comment: That's weird. Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 47.0 here shows your link with only 5 broken characters (not 17).

Comment: That's indeed interesting. I have the exact same thing (17 broken chars) with my PC at work. Win 7 Prof x64, all Windows updates installed, Firefox 47.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find the solution for Firefox:

In `about:config`, set `gfx.font_rendering.fallback.always_use_cmaps` to `true` (default value is `false`).

With that, only 5 of the emoticons in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_(Unicode_block)) remain broken (see screenshot below). That's probably as good as it will get in Windows 7 with Firefox.

Internet Explorer 11 and Chrome both show 17 broken characters.

[image]